# What do we call more button or three dots or three lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

For example in Windows Calculator we get three lines button also called more button, so my question is that what it is called in python if we wanted to create in tkinter.

[image]

As you can see the three lines here in the image, so please help me with the same.

[image]

And How would I bring the pane gradually slowing down.

Comment: FYI, three lines button is usually called [hamburger button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) ;-) (not in tkinter though)

Comment: Why don't you do this: `button = tk.Button(..., text="≡")`?

Comment: Actually I did the same but I wanted to know that how could we bring the pane as shown in post(edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a whole navbar.

Screenshots:

[image: Overview]

[image: Navbar]

Source code:

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

# dictionary of colors:
color = {"nero": "#252726", "orange": "#FF8700", "darkorange": "#FE6101"}

# setting root window:
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tkinter Navbar")
root.config(bg="gray17")
root.geometry("400x600+850+50")

# setting switch state:
btnState = False

# loading Navbar icon image:
navIcon = PhotoImage(file="menu.png")
closeIcon = PhotoImage(file="close.png")

# setting switch function:
def switch():
    global btnState
    if btnState is True:
        # create animated Navbar closing:
        for x in range(301):
            navRoot.place(x=-x, y=0)
            topFrame.update()

        # resetting widget colors:
        brandLabel.config(bg="gray17", fg="green")
        homeLabel.config(bg=color["orange"])
        topFrame.config(bg=color["orange"])
        root.config(bg="gray17")

        # turning button OFF:
        btnState = False
    else:
        # make root dim:
        brandLabel.config(bg=color["nero"], fg="#5F5A33")
        homeLabel.config(bg=color["nero"])
        topFrame.config(bg=color["nero"])
        root.config(bg=color["nero"])

        # created animated Navbar opening:
        for x in range(-300, 0):
            navRoot.place(x=x, y=0)
            topFrame.update()

        # turing button ON:
        btnState = True

# top Navigation bar:
topFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg=color["orange"])
topFrame.pack(side="top", fill=tk.X)

# Header label text:
homeLabel = tk.Label(topFrame, text="NS", font="Bahnschrift 15", bg=color["orange"], fg="gray17", height=2, padx=20)
homeLabel.pack(side="right")

# Main label text:
brandLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Naitik Singhal", font="System 30", bg="gray17", fg="green")
brandLabel.place(x=60, y=250)

# Navbar button:
navbarBtn = tk.Button(topFrame, image=navIcon, bg=color["orange"], activebackground=color["orange"], bd=0, padx=20, command=switch)
navbarBtn.place(x=10, y=10)

# setting Navbar frame:
navRoot = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray17", height=1000, width=300)
navRoot.place(x=-300, y=0)
tk.Label(navRoot, font="Bahnschrift 15", bg=color["orange"], fg="black", height=2, width=300, padx=20).place(x=0, y=0)

# set y-coordinate of Navbar widgets:
y = 80
# option in the navbar:
options = ["Profile", "Settings", "Help", "About", "Feedback"]
# Navbar Option Buttons:
for i in range(5):
    tk.Button(navRoot, text=options[i], font="BahnschriftLight 15", bg="gray17", fg=color["orange"], activebackground="gray17", activeforeground="green", bd=0,command=lambda : showinfo("Info","It do something")).place(x=25, y=y)
    y += 40

# Navbar Close Button:
closeBtn = tk.Button(navRoot, image=closeIcon, bg=color["orange"], activebackground=color["orange"], bd=0, command=switch)
closeBtn.place(x=250, y=6)

# window in mainloop:
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you give a link for the icons you used

Comment: BTW Amazing Work Dude